# Copying directories to JDrive / USB

Tags: c#, .net

I can do this so simply with files, like so:

```
public static void MoveAllFilesFromDesktopToJDrive()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tafe\Desktop\");
            DirectoryInfo Jdrive = new DirectoryInfo(@"J:\");

            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                if (Path.GetFileName(fi.FullName) != "desktop.ini")
                {                      
                    fi.MoveTo(Jdrive.FullName + Path.GetFileName(fi.FullName));
                }    
            }
        }
```

But trying the same operation on directories tells me I can't move directories accross volumes. OK then, so this is what I've tried:

```
 public static void MoveAllDirsFromDeskTopToJDrive()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tafe\Desktop\");
            DirectoryInfo Jdrive = new DirectoryInfo(@"J:\");

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dirs in di.GetDirectories())
            {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(Jdrive + Path.GetFileName(dirs.FullName)); 

            }
        }
```

This copies the names of the files, but not the contents, I would just move the contents like I did with my `MoveAllFilesFromDesktopToJDrive()` method, but the directories contain subdirectories and subdirectories and such, so I can't figure it out. I know a TINY bit about recursion, but not enough to even attempt this. Also, It can't be that hard can it? There has to be something better in the API to facilitate this? If not, any help to complete this method `MoveAllFilesFromDesktopToJDrive()` would be a lifesaver!

Comment: There is no "copy this entire folder" function you can call. This must all be done recursively. There are plenty of results on Google that do what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping this somewhere within your code:

```
    string fileName = "test.txt";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder";
    string targetPath =  @"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\SubDir";

    // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths. 
    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

    // To copy a folder's contents to a new location: 
    // Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

For more details visit this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx